# Can SSH or ping only with Wi-fi not with ethernet on same local network

Tags: ssh, pi-3b+, ethernet

I have two Rpi connected to my router via ethernet

My desktop is also connected to the router via ethernet

I can ssh when connected to my router with wifi from my laptop

**Problem**: Cannot ssh from desktop with ethernet. Also tried ethernet on laptop. Not working.

IP assignment is DHCP for all devices. I haven't changed any IP or made it static on the pi or desktop or laptop.

Cannot ping pi from desktop.
Can ping all devices when connected from wifi

[image]

Comment: the problem seems to be with the desktop and laptop, not with the pi's

Comment: From **rpi0**, can you ping the router and **rpi1** and the laptop and the desktop?